# Removing elements in a list, based on the Mode

Tags: r

I have a list containing 600+ elements. The `summary(list)` shows that the elements have a Mode which is either a `"list"`, `"character"` or `"logical"`. How can I remove all the elements that do not have a Mode as `"list"` without having to manually go through and remove them individually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is.list` with `sapply` to return only those `list` elements that are `list`s:

```
lst[sapply(lst, is.list)]
```

Example:

```
lst <- list(
    list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10),
    "abc",
    TRUE);
lst;
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$a
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#
#[[1]]$b
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "abc"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] TRUE

summary(lst);
#     Length Class  Mode
#[1,] 2      -none- list
#[2,] 1      -none- character
#[3,] 1      -none- logical

# Select list entries that are lists
lst[sapply(lst, is.list)];
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$a
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#
#[[1]]$b
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Or another option using `Filter` (thanks to @Frank):

```
Filter(is.list, lst);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `purr`, we can use `keep`

```
library(purrr)
keep(lst, is.list)
```